# Find the hash of a file in Git history

Tags: git, hash

I try to find the hash of a file at a given point in the history.

```
git ls-files $REVISION $PATH | \
  sed -n 's/^.\{6\} .\+ \([0-9a-f]\{40\}\)\t.*$/\1/p'
```

works, but it looks rather inelegant. It displays mode, type, hash and path to then use `sed` to filter out only the hash. Is there some command that only prints the hash to begin with?

I imagine to have overlooked something more straightforward like `git show --pretty=%hash $REVISION:$PATH`. Does a Git command like this exist?

Comment: `git rev-parse $REVISION:$PATH`

Comment: @AndrewC Yes, this is the correct, concise solution I was looking for. Feel free to turn it into an answer.

Comment: I was thinking it was a duplicate but search is coming up empty for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git provides the `rev-parse` command for printing the SHAs of various items.  Unlike many Git commands (pretty much everything but `git show`) it uses a colon as a separator between revisions and paths.

```
git rev-parse $REVISION:$PATH
```